# Visual C# missing app.config file after build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c#-express-2010

My solution has two exe apps inside. Console application (`Console.exe`) and wpf application (`MyUI.exe`). Wpf application is a startup project, and console one is a small installation tool. Both have app.config file which contains db info. I have problem with this config file after I build the solution. In bin folder I have my wpf app and config file with the same name, e.g.:

```
MyUI.exe and MyUI.exe.config.
```

But there is no config file for console application. Is there any setting I should set to make it right?

When I set build action to content and copy to output... to Copy always then I have `"App.config"` file in bin directory, but there is no `"Console.exe.config"`.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the bin folder of the `Console` application? It sounds like you're just looking in the bin folder of `MyUI`.

Comment: The `app.config` is turned into a file called `YourApp.exe.config` - or in your case - `MyUI.exe.config` - upon compilation. So after a compile - **of course** you won't have an `app.config` anymore - it's now called `MyUI.exe.config` .....

Comment: @RB. Yes the file is in bin folder of my Console application. But the problem is that it is not available in bin folder of my solution.

Comment: @szaman Your *solution* doesn't have a bin folder...! You have 2 projects, each of which have their own bin folder.

Comment: @RB. Yes you are right. It looks like configuration problem. I have to review app properties. Thanks for tip.

Comment: @RB. Ok, there was a problem with project configuration. Thanks for advice. Please make this comment an answer so i will be able to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *solution* output folder - each project has it's own output folder, in which the App.config will be placed (after it's renamed to `[exe_name].config`).